# Handle subpackage execution event with SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I need to elaborate the GUID of every subpackage which is executed by a main package.

In order to do that, I've handled the event **Pre-Execute**, to record every source of Pre-Execute event. The problem is that in **PreExecute** event handler, it isnt possible to know if the source of the event, represented by **SourceID** and **SourceName**, is a subpackage or a task.

I would code only in the main package, in order to centralize the code.

Other attemps:

I've tried with other events, like **PreValidate**, and the issue is the same.

Looking at the standard output (see below) I found a specific log row for subpackages, but I dont know how to read standard output log at runtime.

This is the standard output:

```
Log:
     Name: User:PackageStart
     Computer: COMPUTERNAME
     Operator: username
     Source Name: childpackage
     Source GUID: {9E629F59-5DD1-44AD-BD64-9704353267E2}
     Execution GUID: {4168C4C6-1EC7-41C2-8F2D-98AD3A4F4D82}
     Message: Beginning of package execution.

     Start Time: 2016-05-16 12:28:16
     End Time: 2016-05-16 12:28:16
End Log
```

Thank you

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Source name == ChildPackage is what you're seeing there

Comment: @TabAlleman , in an event I need to know if the SourceID represents a subpackage or a task inside a package. Thanks for asking clarification.

Comment: @billinkc In the events, SourceID and SourceName are the GUID and the Name of the Package/task who raises the event, but it isnt possibile to know whether is a package or a task

Comment: You don't know the names of your subpackages and tasks?

Comment: They are hundereds, and name is parametric, so it's possible to add new packages called by **Execute package** task. So: no, i cannot know the name of every subpackage.

Comment: To restate your question: You have SSIS packages executing under the Package Deployment Model. You are attempting to discern what the ExecutionID is of the child package?

Comment: Not the ExecutionID, but the ID of the package/task (I mean the DTS:DTSID of every DTS:Executable that is a package). Within PreExecute event I can get all  DTS:DTSID but I can't know if they are packages or tasks.

Comment: Do you need to do this analysis at run-time or later? Do you really need Task ID which called your subpackage?

Comment: Best is at run time, to map every ID and execution sequence. Otherwise, everytime someone add or change any package, they have to remap every task-ID and package-ID, but this second solution is more complex and not error-safe.